# What's the dimension of the image of Curl in ${\rm I\!R}^2$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, differential-operators, curl

When working in ${\rm I\!R}^2$, if I apply the Curl operator to a vector field, I obtain a scalar function. Now, the value of this scalar function on a certain point is the Curl on that point. I understand that, by convention, if this value is positive, the Curl is supposed to be a vector pointing "out" from the ${\rm I\!R}^2$ plane and vice-versa.

So my question is: formally speaking, does the Curl function return a scalar, which by convention we understand as a vector that can only take 1 possible direction, and whose orientation depends on the sign of the scalar **(1)**, or, does the Curl function return a three-dimensional vector, with its first two entries equal to zero? **(2)** I know in practical terms, this doesn't make a difference, yet I would like to know the formal definition, which I couldn't find online.

In synthesis, is two dimensional Curl defined as:

$\nabla \times : {\rm I\!R}^2 \to {\rm I\!R}^3$$\!$ **(2)**

or

$\nabla \times : {\rm I\!R}^2 \to {\rm I\!R}$   $\!$ **(1)**

Comment: It has to be the second definition. On the one hand, curl being a scalar in $2$D but a vector in $3$D is a complete coincidence because once you consider all of the possible mixed partials of a vector field (a component's derivative w.r.t. a different variable), there is only one possible difference in $2$D and three possible differences in $3$D, thus it is convenient to hold that information in a vector. However, at a higher level, curls are the result of taking the "imaginary" part of a normed division algebra, which only exist in $(2^n)$D. The imaginary part will always be $(2^n-1)$D.

Comment: To my mind, a vector is an object that transforms like a vector under symmetry transformations. Since the curl in $2$D doesn't transform like a vector (it doesn't even have the right number of components), I would say it has to be a scalar.

Comment: @NinadMunshi by second definition, which do you mean? I just realized I unfortunately placed the "written" and summarized definitions in opposite order.

Comment: @runway44 could you explain why it's (2)?